# Powershell and DirectorySearch exclude OU

Tags: powershell

I have a question on how to exclude a specific OU when running this PS statement. This gives me all the servers in the Domain. I like to excluded the OU called

> OU=RETIRED,OU=SERVER,DC=ABCCORP,dc-com

Tried some filtering but no luck.

```
$ObjFilter = "(operatingsystem=*SERVER*)" 
$objSearch = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher 
$objSearch.PageSize = 15000 
$objSearch.Filter = $ObjFilter 
$objSearch.SearchRoot = "LDAP://dc=ABCCORP,dc=com"
$AllObj = $objSearch.FindAll() | Select-Object @{n='Name';e={$_.properties['name']}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pipe the search result to `Where-Object` and filter based on the LDAP Path.

change:

```
$AllObj = $objSearch.FindAll() | Select-Object @{n='Name';e={$_.properties['name']}}
```

to:

```
$AllObj = $objSearch.FindAll() | Where {-not ($_.Path -match 'OU=RETIRED,OU=SERVER,DC=ABCCORP,dc=com')} | Select-Object @{n='Name';e={$_.properties['name']}}
```

Comment: +1 Using the `path` is even more succinct than my suggestion.

Comment: Thanks to all - both of these statements gives me what I needed 

$AllObj = $objSearch.FindAll()| Where-Object { $_.Properties['distinguishedname'] -notlike "*,OU=RETIRED,OU=SERVER,DC=ABCCORP,dc=com"} | Select-Object @{n='Name';e={$_.properties['name']}} 

$AllObj = $objSearch.FindAll()| Where {-not ($_.Path -match 'OU=RETIRED,OU=SERVER,DC=ABCCORP,dc=com')} | Select-Object @{n='Name';e={$_.properties['name']}}

Comment: @CWL Glad Sean's answer worked for you. Be sure to [mark it as "accepted" when you are able](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). This will help others, with similar issues, find your question easier. Also note that [an explicit "thanks" on SE](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/how-to-say-thanks-in-an-answer/) works a bit different than other forums. :)